# Function related question with graphs

Tags: functions

I will just get straight to the point so I had a test there was question [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93pAv.jpg can anyone tell why the functions summed up as 1+1+1

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your question. Then write down $f(0)$, $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $f(5)$. Then plug the correct value in the expression that you want to calculate. Note that the picture is not accurate

Comment: sure will keep in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to plug in the function values.  That is $$ f(f(1)) = f(|2 - |1-3||) = f(0) = |2 - | 0 - 3 | = 1.$$

Comment: thanks yaa that was dumb